# Errors with bridged interfaces

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge

I have problem with Debian running as a VirtualBox Guest. I can set up a bridge but it flood the logs with a lot of errors and system becomes unusable. Errors such as:

> Nov 12 16:30:55 jessie-gnome kernel: [  737.277528] br0: received packet on eth0 with own address as source address
>
> Nov 12 16:31:00 jessie-gnome kernel: [  742.280085] net_ratelimit: 47185 callbacks suppressed
>
> Nov 12 16:31:00 jessie-gnome kernel: [  742.280088] br0:
> received packet on eth1 with own address as source address
>
> Nov 12 16:31:00 jessie-gnome kernel: [  742.280178] br0: received packet on eth1 with own address as source address
>
> Nov 12 16:31:00 jessie-gnome kernel: [  742.280282] br0: received packet on eth1 with own address as source address

My interfaces files has:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback



iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.80.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.80.0
    gateway 192.168.80.1
     bridge_stp off       # disable Spanning Tree Protocol
     bridge_fd 0          # no forwarding delay
     bridge_ports eth0 eth1
     up iptables -I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT
```

And these are the process that consume more time of CPU:

```
  580 avahi     20   0   32224   2756   2492 R 16,2  0,2   1:30.48 avahi-daemon                                                                     
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 R 15,5  0,0   1:43.27 ksoftirqd/0                                                                      
  923 root      20   0  215988  34140  18968 S 15,2  2,2   0:34.59 Xorg                                                                             
 1261 sergio    20   0 1330672 202952  68820 R 12,9 13,2   0:32.71 gnome-shell                                                                      
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S 12,6  0,0   1:22.70 rcu_sched
```

OS is Debian 8.

How can I fix those errors?

Comment: why are you bridging eth0 and eth1 in a VM?  what problem are you trying to solve by doing that?   what are those interfaces on the virtualisation host and what are they for?

Comment: Because I'm trying to virtualize a Linux bridge. `4: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Comment: i meant, are they connected to different physical networks, with different IP subnets on the host?  are they bridged on the host?  is bridging the two networks together really what you need, or just routing between them?  or just the ability for the VM to communicate on both nets (in which case you don't need to bridge them in the VM)

Answer (score 1):

When a Linux bridge receives a packet with a new source MAC address from a particular bridge port, it stores the MAC address along with the port number in its MAC learning table. A timer is associated with each entry in the table, so that the entry expires after a certain period (so-called “ageing time”), unless it is refreshed before then. By default the ageing time in a Linux bridge is set to 300 seconds.

To resolve this problem, we need to disable MAC address learning in a Linux bridge. To do that, we set the the “ageing time” to 0 with following command:

`sudo brctl setageing br0 0`

References: https://medium.com/@tienbm90/resolved-br0-received-packet-on-xx-with-own-address-as-source-address-fad895d410a4

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to respond to such an old post
Also been seeing this on RPI4 with raspbian (Debian 10 Buster)
I have a bridge eth0.1 and wlan0.
Seems to occur when I run iftop.

I suspect when a process enables filtering / listening on bridge the wlan0 and eth0.1 which have the mac results in this messages and also disable of wlan0.
I worked around this with

```
#!/bin/bash
dmesg -T -x --follow |
while read LINE
do
   if [[ "$LINE" == *"received packet on wlan0 with own address"* ]]; then
      sleep 1
      echo "RESTART hostapd: $LINE" >> /var/log/wlan0.log
      systemctl restart hostapd
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If those messages keep coming as a flood, the bridge is probably configured NOT to use the Spanning Tree Protocol. And, some external network attached to your soft-bridge closes a loop between your two bridged ports.

To solve the problem, try: `brctl stp br0 on` .

Apparently the default may as well be STP=off. That's what it was in my case, on a pretty bare kernel 5.2.7 early on in the initrd boot process. I'm trying to PXE-boot a diskless client, with a soft-bridge established in the Linux user space before "ipconfig" does its job :-)

Side note: when creating a bridge, the br0 interface will take the MAC address of the first physical interface added. Which probably doesn't have anything to do with the "problem" debated here... but matters to me when PXE-booting. I prefer not to waste two or more leases on a single diskless client.